# AngularJS dropdown box width prevent from auto-resizing

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-options

**HTML**

```
<select class = "box" ng-model="selected" ng-options="person.id as person.name for person in people" >
<option value="">----select----</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    height: 21px !important;
    width: 96%;
}
```

Hi, I'm updating the `$scope.people` and call `$scope.$apply(...` to update the dropdown. When I do this, the dropdown select box automatically increases the size and adjust the size according to my content. My content isn't even close to overflowing though. Would be great if I could get some help! In the link, `$scope.people` is statically defined since I wasn't able to demo the messaging service I'm using at the moment. I could just fix the width into a certain px size. But then when the browser window size is changed, the box size won't adjust according to that. Would be great to know if there's a way to fix this! Thanks :) http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7937/

**Update**
I didn't mention this because I didn't know this would be the problem. This select box is in the table. It's within the `<td></td>` tag if that makes any difference..

Comment: what are you updating it with ? It will help a lot if you could create plunk.

Comment: @Alok I'm using a messaging service within the company. I'm updating the people with an array that has objects with properties, id and name.

Comment: could you give me a sample of JSON that you update it with?

Comment: @Alok At first, `$scope.people` is an empty list. And then something like above is provided. The box size changes when the content is populated.

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/4et7da1s/1/  ... Should it have replicated your issue ??

Comment: @Alok Hmm I'm not sure what you tried to solve here. My update has no issues. When the response call back from the request I send, my $scope.people will be updated with different contents. The problem is when it's updated, the size of the select box also changes. So it ruins my style of the form. I would like to prevent the box changing the size regardless of the contents :)

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you don't fix the height and width of the box and let bootstrap make it responsive on its own

Try this, it is working

```
<div class="container">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select class = "box" ng-model="selected" ng-options="person.id as person.name for person in people" >
    <option value="">----select----</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

and in css:

```
.box {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this but the select box increases its size, as soon as the $scope.people is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4et7da1s/2/

You can solve the problem with a mix of max-width and making the width as auto.

Something like this:

```
.box {
    height: 21px !important;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 20%;
}
```